# Get the values of properties - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, for-loop, properties

I have a `for loop` that runs over a *JSON* object and returns the properties in the console. What I am trying to do is return also the value of that property in the console.

This is the code

```
   for (var i in response) {
       console.log(i); //return the property to the console
    }
```

How can I get the value of `response.i` and not just the name of the property?

Comment: just use `console.log(response[i]);`

Comment: Time to read up on simple loops -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @adeneo I do lack some basic stuff from time to time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following :

```
console.log(response[i]);
```

You are iterating throw the object, but `i` is number of the property in the collection, not the property value.

Comment: Thanks, will accept in 2 minutes. I was trying to get response.i for some reason....